# What is ${a} and => in my code?

Tags: javascript

```js
function unusedDigits(...a){
  return `0123456789`.split('').filter(
    b => `${a}`.split('').indexOf(b) == -1
  ).join('');
}

document.write(unusedDigits(12345))
```

1. What is **`${a}`**
2. What is **=>**

And if someone could break down this code for me that would be amazing!

Comment: They are called [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1, What is ${a}

That's a substitution in a new JavaScript [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (added by ES2015). It swaps in the value of `a` where it occurs. Any arbitrary expression is accepted.

> 2, what is =>

It's an ES2015 [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

You didn't ask, but the `...` before the `a` argument in the function declaration is a "[rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)" that says "give me the (rest of) the arguments supplied to the function as an array.

> And if someone could break down this code for me that would be amazing!

It returns a string containing the digits that don't appear in the string form of any of the arguments passed to it:

- The `unusedDigits` function accepts any number of arguments, which it receives as an array accessed via the `a` argument (thanks to the ES2015 `...` rest operator in the declaration of the `a` argument).
- It takes a string of the digits 0-9 and splits it to create an array (e.g. `['0', '1', ...]`).
- Then it loops through that array via the `filter` function, getting a new array of only entries that the `filter` callback says should be kept.
- The `filter` callback (an ES2015 arrow function) creates a string containing the `a` array using an ES2015 template string. Since that involves calling `a.toString()` implicitly, it ends up doing `a.join(",")` implicitly (since that's what `Array#toString` does) and then checks if the digit being checked (`b`) appears in the resulting string. (This is not very efficient; there's no reason to recreate the string each time, and no reason to use a template string here.) It returns a truthy value only if the digit wasn't in the string (`indexOf` returned `-1`).
- Then it assembles a string at the end from the surviving digits and returns it.

Here's a more efficient version, FWIW: [Live Copy on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20unusedDigits%20%3D%20(function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20digits%20%3D%20%5B0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20unusedDigits(...a)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20astring%20%3D%20String(a)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20digits.filter(b%20%3D%3E%20astring.indexOf(b)%20%3D%3D%20-1).join(%22%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D)()%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(unusedDigits(12345))%3B)

```
let unusedDigits = (function() {
    const digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    return function unusedDigits(...a) {
        let astring = String(a);
        return digits.filter(b => astring.indexOf(b) == -1).join("");
    };
})();

console.log(unusedDigits(12345));
```

And the same function in ES5:

```
var unusedDigits = (function() {
    var digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return function unusedDigits() {
        var astring = String(slice.call(arguments));
        return digits.filter(function(b) { return astring.indexOf(b) == -1}).join("");
    };
})();
```

(The `slice` thing turns the pseudo-array `arguments` into a true array.)

```js
var unusedDigits = (function() {
    var digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    return function unusedDigits() {
        var astring = String(slice.call(arguments));
        return digits.filter(function(b) { return astring.indexOf(b) == -1}).join("");
    };
})();

snippet.log(unusedDigits(12345));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function unusedDigits(...a){
  return `0123456789`.split('').filter(b=>`${a}`.split('').indexOf(b)==-1).join('');
 }

 alert(unusedDigits(12345))
```

...a in the first line is the rest operator - this will assign the arguments array to the variable a within the function body (so you don't have to deal with Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) anymore. In this case var a = [12345]

'0123456789'.split('') will split out all of the digits from 0-9 into an array - which we then filter over.

b => `${a}`.split('').indexOf(b)==-1 is the predicate function for filter. => is known as 'fat arrow syntax' or 'arrow function'. This is ES6 - it's a shorthand syntax for functions that also binds the current 'this' binding to the function. If the body is on the same line, it will return the expression implicitly.

`${a}` is the template string syntax - in this case coercing our arguments array [12345] into '12345', which we are then splitting to do an index of operation to see if the current digit (b) of 0-9 digits is in the split arguments array. At the end of it we return the result of filtering for all those digits 0-9 that are not in the arguments array, joined as a string - in this case '06789'.

Answer (score 0):

Language features:

```
`${1}`;
// gives "1"
var v = 1; `${v}${v}`;
// gives "11"
x => x != "2";
// same as function (x) { return x != "2"; } 
(x => x != "2")("1");
// gives true
((u, ...v) => v)(1, 2, 3);
// gives [2, 3]
```

String and Array methods:

```
"123".split("");
// gives ["1", "2", "3"]
["1", "2", "3"].join("");
// gives "123"
["1", "2", "3"].indexOf("2");
// gives 1
["1", "2", "3"].indexOf("4");
// gives -1
["1", "2", "3"].filter(x => x != "2");
// gives ["1", "3"]
```

Something close to your code (the converting functions are pretty crappy, don't use them as they are, I just want to provide some context for the previous code):

```js
var itos = i => `${i}`; // integer to string
var stoa = s => s.split(""); // string to array
var atos = a => a.join(""); // array to string
var isIn = (x, set) => set.indexOf(x) != -1;

var unusedDigits = function (i) {
  // allDigits is ["0", "1", ..., "9"]
  var allDigits = stoa("0123456789");
  // if i is 12 then usedDigits is ["1", "2"]
  var usedDigits = stoa(itos(i));
  // convert filtering result to a string
  return atos(
    // make a set of digits not in usedDigits
    allDigits.filter(
      // d will be "0" then "1" ... until "9"
      d => !isIn(d, usedDigits)
    )
  );
};

document.write(JSON.stringify(
  unusedDigits(13579) // gives "02468"
));
```

Comment: @downvoter Well, I just wanted to contribute in a different way than TJCrowder. If you don't like it please explain, it would be more constructive. Thanks.